How to set up a Firestore listener (to get realtime updates) inside a libs file instead of inside a Vue SFC?
I'm working on a chat app that uses Vue3 and Firebase. My project is structured in the following manner:

src/pages - contains the .vue files of the pages
src/services/firebase.js - contains the code to initialise the firebase app
src/services/firebase_firestore.js - contains all CRUD methods related to the Firestore db

The feature that I'm trying to implement is to display realtime changes that are made to the chat feed. So I'm using the onSnapshot() function of Firebase.
The conversation between the sender (currently signed in user) and a recipient is shown in the HomePage.vue. For now, I have a button that will trigger loadAllMessages() to fetch the chat feed after the user searches and selects another user:
<script setup>
import { addNewMessage, getUserDetailsWithEmail, registerMessageListener } from "../services/firebase_firestore.js";

const messages = ref([]);
.
.
.
const loadAllMessages = () => {
  if (!recipient) return;

  messages.value = registerMessageListener(sender.id, recipient.id);
  console.log("Messages received: ")
  console.log(messages.value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <div id="chat_feed" style="...">
      <div style="border: 1px solid gray; margin: 1px"
          v-for="message in messages"
      >
        <p>
          {{ message.text_message }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button @click="loadAllMessages">Load All Messages</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Inside the registerMessageListener() function situated in src/services/firebase_firestore.js, I set up a listener to the messages collection to fetch realtime updates between the 2 users:
import { addDoc, collection, getDocs, getFirestore, and, or, orderBy, query, where, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

let unsubscribe = null;
.
.
.
const registerMessageListener = (senderId, recipientId) => {
    if (unsubscribe) unsubscribe();

    const messages = [];
    const messagesCollection = collection(db, "messages");

    const q = query(
        messagesCollection,
        or(
            and(
                where("sender_id", "==", senderId),
                where("recipient_id", "==", recipientId)
            ),
            and(
                where("sender_id", "==", recipientId),
                where("recipient_id", "==", senderId)
            )
        )
    );

    unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                messages.push(
                    {
                        id: change.doc.id,
                        ...change.doc.data()
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    });

    return messages;
}

export { registerMessageListener };

Expected outcome

Chat feed displayed inside <div id="chat_feed">
Chat feed updated after a message is sent

Actual outcome

Chat feed not displayed

I do see the array of messages logged inside the console:

Solution that I tried
I wrote the registerMessageListener function inside HomePage.vue instead of inside src/services/firebase_firestore.js. By doing so, the chat feed was displayed and updated when a new message was sent. However, this way of implementing it does not comply with my project structure, where I want to place all CRUD operations into a separate file.
From what I've researched I think this is a Vue issue with regards to component lifecycles, but I'm not quite sure what the exact problem is.

Are there no different messages sets per app with different senderId/recipientId pair? Then you likely need reactive state like messages that can be shared between comps. I.e. global store. Basically move const messages = ref([]) to firebase_firestore.js. See https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api . Is messages unique to a comp that uses it? Then make registerMessageListener  a composable that receives refs to act on, or make messages a ref inside registerMessageListener

I don't quite understand your comment. Could you please rephrase? What do you mean by comp? :) Also, there's just a single messages collection in Firestore that stores all messages between pairs of users. Now that you've mentioned it, a collection per user pair seems more efficient.

Comp(onent). If it's global then this "move const messages = ref([]) to firebase_firestore.js" is applicable. You can use a map instead of an array if you need to store multiple collections
